# Which of the Doodle Jump themes have special play modes?

Tags: ios, doodle-jump

I have briefly played each of the different themes in Doodle Jump. I noticed when playing the World Cup theme that the gameplay is slightly different - instead of appearing randomly, monsters appear in groups, coloured like particular football teams.

I didn't notice anything special for the other themes. Are there any differences to them besides the colouring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, the World Cup one came out just before the world cup, so it was specially designed to be like football fields where you went up towards the goaltender.

The rest of the themes just offer variations of the same, with addition of things like bubbles for underwater, or low visibility for night mode.